# Django won't change url on redirect

Tags: python, django

Upon registration I check the user_type and move the user to one of three web pages.

It is showing the correct page layout but the url stays the same as the registration page.

EG: url says "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/register/"
Page shows: "user type 1 information"

I thought using redirect should change the url but it doesn't seem to be working.

views.py:

```
def register(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():


 #       profile = form.save(commit=False)
 #       profile.user = request.user
 #       profile.save()

        user = form.save()
        profile = user.userprofile
        user_group = form.cleaned_data.get('user_type')
        profile.user_type = user_group
        profile.save()


      #  form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user_group = form.cleaned_data.get('user_type')
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        login(request, user)

        print(user_group)
        print(type(user_group))

        if user_group == '1':
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/users/business/")
    #        return 
    #        HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/business/')

    #           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:business'))
    #    return redirect(request, 'users/business.html')

        elif user_group == '2':
            return redirect(request, 'users/student.html')
        elif user_group == '3':
            return redirect(request, 'users/tourist.html')
    #    else:
     #       return redirect('main:index')
    else:
        print(RegisterForm.errors)

else:
    form = RegisterForm()


def business_view(request):
#    return redirect(request, 'users/business.html')
#    return HttpResponseRedirect('users/business.html')

#      return redirect('/users/business/')
  return redirect('users/business')

def student_view(request):
    return redirect(request, 'users/student.html')

def tourist_view(request):
    return redirect(request, 'users/tourist.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 # Login page 
  #url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, 
 name='login'),

url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, 
name='login'),

#url(r'^login/$', views.log_in, name='login'),



# Register page
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),


# Business page
#url(r'^business/$', views.business_view, name='business'),
url(r'^$',views.business_view),


# Student page
url(r'^student/$', views.student_view, name='student'),

# Tourist page 
url(r'^tourist/$', views.tourist_view, name = 'tourist'),

 ]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you want to add the `.html` add the end of the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *urlname* only in redirect argument, i.e. to redirect on student page use `return redirect('student')` (name defined while defining urls). Eg.

```
if user_group == '2':
      return redirect('student')
```

Also in your views where you want to show html page, use `render` instead. Eg.

```
from django.shorcuts import render
def student_view(request):
    return render(request, 'users/student.html')
```

Comment: Ohh ok, I initially had def student_view as a render also.  Ended up changing it trying to fix things.

With these changes though I get a Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Comment: I got it working with:

            if user_group == '1':
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:business'))

thanks for the help, greatly appreciated