# Why does Django views.py redirect to another view without changing the url?

Tags: django, python-3.x, redirect

Im trying to redirect to another URL from my views.py after user Input - the view actually changes but unfortunately the browsers' URL stays the same.

urls.py:

```
path('start/', StartProject.as_view(), name='start_url'),

path('settings_1/', settings_1_view, name='settings_1_url'),

path('settings_2/', settings_2_view, name='settings_2_url'),

path('settings_3/', settings_3_view, name='settings_3_url'),
```

My views.py: Here i try to redirect the user to another page after selection.

views.py

```
class StartProject(TemplateView):

    template = "start.html"

    def get(self, request):
        class_form = ClassChoiceForm(request.POST or None, initial={'class_select': 1})
        context = {
            'class_form': class_form
        }
        return render(request, self.template, context)

    def post(self, request):
        class_form = ClassChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if class_form.is_valid():
            choice = class_form.cleaned_data['class_select']
            choice = int(choice)

            if choice == 1:
                return redirect('settings_1/')

            elif choice == 2:
                return redirect('/settings_2/')

            elif choice == 3:
                return redirect('/settings_3/')

            else:
                self.get(request)

        else:
            raise Http404


def settings_1_view(request):
    context = {
    }
    template = "settings_1.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The User selection is been made by radio buttons, which value is posted to the views.py / Checking the value in the if- statements, it should redirect the user to the selected page. (I need the user selection for further calculation)

POST template choice.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} TITLE {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<form id="post" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">{% csrf_token %}

    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <center>
        <div class="col align-self-center" style="min-width:700px; margin-bottom:90px; margin-top:30px; horizontal-align: center;"> 
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#fff">
                    <br>

                            <img src="{% static 'personal/img/item1.png' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:170px; width:130px' alt="item1_image">
                            <p>Selection 1</p>

                            {{ class_form.class_select.0 }}
                            {{ class_form.class_select.errors }}

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#fff">
                    <br>

                        <img src="{% static 'personal/img/item2.png' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:170px; max-width:100px' alt="item2_image">
                        <p>Selection 2</p>

                            {{ class_form.class_select.1 }}
                            {{ class_form.class_select.errors }}

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#fff">
                    <br>


                        <img src="{% static 'personal/img/item3.png' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:170px;max-width:130px' alt="item3_image">
                        <p>Selection 3</p>

                            {{ class_form.class_select.2 }}
                            {{ class_form.class_select.errors }}
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <center>
                        <button type="submit" style="width:200">Submit</button>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </center>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py

```
class ClassChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [
        (1, 'item1'),
        (2, 'item2'),
        (3, 'item3')
                ]
    class_select = forms.CharField(label=None, widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))
```

Its indeed getting the User Input from the form, takes the right path, shows it but not changing the related url in the browser. So if i refresh the page, the old one gets loaded. Does anybody have an idea??

```
[After Redirect same URL:][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSso3.jpg
```

Comment: This code doesn't do what you claim. Are you using Ajax to do this POST?

Comment: yes, in my base.html i have a ajax/jquery loaded. Is there a known conflict? I gonna add the template

Comment: Okay, really seems to be an ajax problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
return redirect('https://yourUrl.com/settings_1/')
```

[Here is the explanation you need about rediret](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

[Also you might want to work with the HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

[Check also this answer it might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923282/django-wont-change-url-on-redirect)

[And how to proper work with reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#attributes-set-by-application-code)

[Django docs about reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

Comment: No unfortunately the same problem! The redirect is working (in the first place) but not changing the URL :/

Comment: this is all not working for me. I checked this solution already [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923282/django-wont-change-url-on-redirect). As well as HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: Not really! I have a temporary solution by commenting an ajax import in my base.html.

Comment: Please if you find what's and why is wrong post it here